# C# Add UserControl to a datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I wanna add a usercontrol in a datagridview, my usercontrol is very simple :

```
public partial class UpDownControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler UpClick;
    public event EventHandler DownClick;

    public UpDownControl(string id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Tag = id;
    }

    void BDownClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(DownClick!=null)
            DownClick(this,e);
    }

    void BUpClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(UpClick!=null)
            UpClick(this,e);
    }
}
```

All I wanna do is add this control in the first column of a datagridview, I tried to find out a solution by myself, but in vain I didnt find one. Don't tell me to go see this link,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx, I read it all but I didnt find a way to do it with MY usercontrol.

So, this is my current code :

```
for(int i=0;i<lposte.Count;++i)
{
    UpDownControl updown = new UpDownControl("test1");
    updown.DownClick += new EventHandler(testvincdown);
    updown.UpClick += new EventHandler(testvincup);

    rang = 1;
    CustomColumn col = new CustomColumn();
    CustomeCell cell = new CustomeCell();

    col.CellTemplate = cell;

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
    dataGridView1.Rows.add(updown);
}

public class CustomColumn : DataGridViewColumn 
{
    public CustomColumn() : base(new CustomeCell()) { }
    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CustomeCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("It should be a custom Cell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}
public class CustomeCell : DataGridViewCell
{
    public CustomeCell() : base() { }
    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(UpDownControl);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. PS: Sorry if my english is not perfect, I did my best.

Thank you.

Vinc